# Very bad query plan in PostgreSQL 9.6

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have a performance problem with PostgreSQL 9.6.17 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5
20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39), 64-bit). Sometimes very inefficient query plan is chosen for relatively simple query.

There is `dir_current` table with 750M rows:

`\d sf.dir_current`

```
                                         Table "sf.dir_current"
       Column       |    Type     | Collation | Nullable |                    Default
--------------------+-------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
 id                 | bigint      |           | not null | nextval('sf.object_id_seq'::regclass)
 volume_id          | bigint      |           | not null |
 parent_id          | bigint      |           |          |
 blocks             | sf.blkcnt_t |           |          |
 rec_aggrs          | jsonb       |           | not null |
...
Indexes:
    "dir_current_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id), tablespace "sf_current"
    "dir_current_parentid_idx" btree (parent_id), tablespace "sf_current"
    "dir_current_volumeid_id_unq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (volume_id, id), tablespace "sf_current"
Foreign-key constraints:
    "dir_current_parentid_fk" FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES sf.dir_current(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

(some columns omitted as they're irrelevant here).

Now, a temporary table is created with ca. 1K rows:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE dir_process AS (
  SELECT sf.dir_current.id, volume_id, parent_id, depth, size, blocks, atime, ctime, mtime, sync_time, local_aggrs FROM sf.dir_current
  WHERE ....
);
CREATE INDEX dir_process_indx ON dir_process(volume_id, id);
ANALYZE dir_process;
```

The actual condition `....` doesn't matter here - it selects some rows to be processed.

Here is a query which is sometimes very slow:

```
  SELECT dir.id, dir.volume_id, dir.parent_id, dir.rec_aggrs, dir.blocks FROM sf.dir_current AS dir
  INNER JOIN dir_process ON dir.parent_id = dir_process.id AND dir.volume_id = dir_process.volume_id
  WHERE dir.volume_id = ANY(volume_ids)
```

A few slow plans:

```
duration: 1822060.789 ms  plan:
Merge Join  (cost=150260.47..265775.37 rows=1 width=456) (actual rows=14305 loops=1)
  Merge Cond: (dir.volume_id = dir_process.volume_id)
  Join Filter: (dir.parent_id = dir_process.id)
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 23117117695
  ->  Index Scan using dir_current_volumeid_id_unq on dir_current dir  (cost=0.12..922747.05 rows=624805 width=456) (actual rows=1231600 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (volume_id = ANY ('{88}'::bigint[]))
  ->  Sort  (cost=966.16..975.55 rows=18770 width=16) (actual rows=23115900401 loops=1)
        Sort Key: dir_process.volume_id
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1648kB
        ->  Seq Scan on dir_process  (cost=0.00..699.70 rows=18770 width=16) (actual rows=18770 loops=1)
```

```
duration: 10140968.829 ms  plan:
Merge Join  (cost=0.17..8389.13 rows=1 width=456) (actual rows=819 loops=1)
  Merge Cond: (dir_process.volume_id = dir.volume_id)
  Join Filter: (dir.parent_id = dir_process.id)
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2153506735
  ->  Index Only Scan using dir_process_indx on dir_process  (cost=0.06..659.76 rows=1166 width=16) (actual rows=1166 loops=1)
        Heap Fetches: 1166
  ->  Index Scan using dir_current_volumeid_id_unq on dir_current dir  (cost=0.12..885276.20 rows=602172 width=456) (actual rows=2153506389 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (volume_id = ANY ('{5}'::bigint[]))
```

```
duration: 12524111.200 ms  plan:
Merge Join  (cost=480671.74..878819.79 rows=1 width=456) (actual rows=62 loops=1)
  Merge Cond: (dir.volume_id = dir_process.volume_id)
  Join Filter: (dir.parent_id = dir_process.id)
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 153595373018
  ->  Index Scan using dir_current_volumeid_id_unq on dir_current dir  (cost=0.12..922747.05 rows=624805 width=456) (actual rows=2360101 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (volume_id = ANY ('{441}'::bigint[]))
  ->  Sort  (cost=2621.42..2653.96 rows=65080 width=16) (actual rows=153593012980 loops=1)
        Sort Key: dir_process.volume_id
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 4587kB
        ->  Seq Scan on dir_process  (cost=0.00..1580.80 rows=65080 width=16) (actual rows=65080 loops=1)
```

The first reaction is as usual: "do I have up to date statistics?". The answer is yes: `dir_current` is changed frequently but is also analyzed ca. once an hour. `dir_process` is analyzed as soon as it's created.
Note that estimated number of rows matches pretty well:

- est. 624805, actual=1231600
- est. 624805, actual=2360101

Where the estimates are way off is the inner loop of merge join which actually shows the number of rows times the number of loops (153593012980 or 2153506389 or 23115900401). Poor executor is spinning in the inner loop, iterating over all rows with a given `volume_id`, looking for a given `id`.

The biggest problem seems to be that Postgres chooses to do a merge join on a very inefficient condition: `dir.volume_id = dir_process.volume_id` instead of `dir.parent_id = dir_process.id`. For a given `volume_id` there is a few million rows in `dir_current`, for a given `parent_id` there is hundreds or thousands of rows, but not millions.
The other effective query plan is a nested loop, where outer loop is iterating over `dir_process` and using an index to fetch the row from `dir_current`.

I understand that I could disable merge join before running this query but I was wondering if there is a better solution.

Any more idea about what can be done to avoid this inefficient plan? How is it possible that it's chosen over nested loops?

Comment: A) This is a question for the [DBA site](https://dba.stackexchange.com). B) Questions about the performance of a version of Postgres that at this point is downright ancient aren't going to go very far. Postgres 13.2 is out and has made *huge* gains. C) Updating your system once every six years isn't exactly living on the edge, you may want to migrate.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the **complete** execution plans generated using `explain (analyze, buffers, format text)` - not  just a "simple" explain or a redacted version of the "full" plan

Comment: Will post to DBA, thanks.
I don't have control over PG version, right now it's 9.6. Last time I checked it was still a supported version of PG.
I can't post `explain (analyze, buffers, format text)` as this issue occurs only sometimes so I need to depend on the logs. This query is run thousands of times a day and only a few (say 5 a day) result in an inefficient query.

Comment: @gozdal: you could try the [auto explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html) module maybe that gets you a plan for the slow executions.

Comment: CREATE INDEX dir_process_indx ON dir_process(volume_id, id); -- try reversing the columns which would put the most selective column first

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name those plans are from `auto_explain` module.

Comment: @bobflux will try that. Can you explain how this would help Postgres avoid the very inefficient merge join?

Comment: Mostly just a hunch. Also I don't understand why there is an index UNIQUE(volume_id, id), since id is the PK it is already unique. And if you search on id, there is the PK index. So is it just used as an index on volume_id? In this case, adding the id column is just wasting space. So, replacing it with an index on (volume_id,parent_id) would cover both columns in your join and that could be very useful.